# Why won't Windows Server 2008 R2 install on my HDD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

> I'm attempting to install Windows Server 2008 R2 on my HDD the
>   installation well until I reach the end of the installation. I get an
>   error saying. " Copyright (c) 2013 Hewlett-Packard Development Company
>   L.P. IDE device failed. Copyright (c) 2013 American Megatrends, Inc.
>   819 MB "

The hard drive is a 250 GB SATA 150 HDD The hard drive is not detected in several computers that I've tried.  I'm kind of at a lost as to how to proceed.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before?

Comment: "The hard drive is not detected in several computers that I've tried." - Is it detected in others? Perhaps it's a bad Hard Drive

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'm going to return it. @JoeTaylor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard drive is not detected in several computers that I've tried." - Is it detected in others? Perhaps it's a bad Hard Drive.
The error message that you are getting says " IDE device failed" This looks pretty terminal for the drive I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly a broken HDD.